# react-native: android: Modal height with soft menu

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog

On a `Samsung Galaxy S8` which has a soft bottom menu bar, my full-screen modal components randomly render with either full-screen height or they leave room for the soft menu bar. This behavior is completely random and only limited to `Modal` components. I'm on the latest version of react-native of `0.57.5` but this has been happening over several versions.

I'm using the full-screen AppTheme style like below:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ReactNative.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">`

The status bar is also being hidden like so:

`StatusBar.setHidden(true);`

As can be seen in the screenshots, the background bleeds through in the cases where the `Modal` decides to not render with full height.

Has anyone encountered and fixed such an issue?

[image: full screen]
[image: not full screen]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, if you are using react-native-modal according to the documentation you must use [react-native-extra-dimensions-android](https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android).

> React-Native has a few issues detecting the correct device width/height of some devices.
>   If you're experiencing this issue, you'll need to install react-native-extra-dimensions-android.
>   Then, provide the real window height (obtained from react-native-extra-dimensions-android) to the modal:

```
  render() {
  const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const deviceHeight = Platform.OS === "ios"
    ? Dimensions.get("window").height
    : require("react-native-extra-dimensions-android").get("REAL_WINDOW_HEIGHT");

  return (
  <Modal
    isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
    deviceWidth={deviceWidth}
    deviceHeight={deviceHeight}
  >
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
    </View>
  </Modal>
  )
}
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal